# Using CustomParameter with Visual Studio Multi-Project Template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-templates

I would like to be able to create a [Multi-Project Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308(v=vs.100).aspx) for a solution which contains the following two projects (*where the interface should include a reference to the business layer*).:

- `<proj_name>.interface`
- `<proj_name>.business`.

Normally, you can include [`$safeprojectname$`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185311(v=vs.100).aspx), which has:

> The name provided by the user in the New Project dialog box

However, as pointed out in the article [Build a multi-project visual studio template](http://blog.tonysneed.com/2011/09/14/build-a-multi-project-visual-studio-template/)

> The problem here is that within each child template, *$safeprojectname$* represents the current project name. There needs to be a way to pass in the root *$safeprojectname$* from the parent template.

I'm trying to implement the solution suggested in this SO question [VS 2010 Multi-Project Template: Inter-Project References](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12929020/1366033), by using [`CustomParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247063.aspx), but am running into trouble.

**My Zipped Up Template Directory looks like this:**

- MultiTemplate.vstemplate
- Interface

  - InterfaceTemplate.vstemplate
  - MyTemplate.Interface.csproj
- Business

  - BusinessTemplate.vstemplate
  - MyTemplate.Business.csproj

You can download the [Entire Directory](http://sdrv.ms/1coSCaj), but here are some select snippets

**MultiTemplate.vstemplate**

```xml
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="ProjectGroup">
  <TemplateData><!--Removed for brevity --></TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <CustomParameters>
      <CustomParameter Name="$SolutionName$" Value="$safeprojectname$"/>
    </CustomParameters>
    <ProjectCollection>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Interface">
        Interface\InterfaceTemplate.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Business">
        Business\BusinessTemplate.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
    </ProjectCollection>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

**Interface\InterfaceTemplate.vstemplate**

```xml
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Project">
  <TemplateData><!--Removed for brevity --></TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <Project TargetFileName="MyTemplate.Interface.csproj" 
             File="MyTemplate.Interface.csproj"
             ReplaceParameters="true">
    </Project>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

**MyTemplate.Interface.csproj**

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\$SolutionName$.Business\$SolutionName$.Business.csproj">
    <Project>{E5511F75-5B9C-4816-B991-E09225661CF4}</Project>
    <Name>MyTemplate.Business</Name>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

## The Problem

When I create a new project, the `$SolutionName$` portion of the string does not get replaced.  Instead it just stays the same.

**Q**: *How can I properly pass this information from the Multi-Project Template to each of the child templates?*

Bonus points if you can figure out how to replace the `<name>` tag value, as token replacements don't seem to work on it.

Comment: From my point of view (seeing that for my project the described method is functional) the only reason for VS not replacing the tokens may be the project type. Sadly I have little time right now to test this but I advise you to make a similar template with a Web project type and check if the tokens are replaced only for the Web project type...

Comment: Would you consider changing your accepted answer? The original answer is hosted only on Codeplex, which will be shutting down later in 2017.

Comment: As the author of the currently marked answer, i support changing it to the answer by @friggle. Using the new built in functionality is a better solution.

Comment: @TroyPalacino, yep, good call.  Thanks for the nudge.  Have some bounty points as an accept consolation prize

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 finally added a built-in way to do this with [`ProjectTemplateLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171398.aspx)

The `CopyParameters` attribute will enable child access to all the variables of the parent template, with the prefix of `ext_`.

You don't even need CustomParameters for this. Change your ProjectTemplateLink to this:

```xml
<ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Interface" CopyParameters="true">
  Interface\InterfaceTemplate.vstemplate
</ProjectTemplateLink>
```

And then you can achieve your goal in the child `.csproj`  like so:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\$ext_safeprojectname$.Business\$ext_safeprojectname$.Business.csproj">
    <Project>{E5511F75-5B9C-4816-B991-E09225661CF4}</Project>
    <Name>MyTemplate.Business</Name>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: how would you rename files using templates?

Comment: is it possible to allow cusotm parameters values to be passed down to child templates?

Comment: @AlexGordon I just used custom parametrs and the $ext_mycustomparam$ worked.

Answer (score 3):

**Full Disclosure**: I am the creator of the below mentioned project.

I solved the issue of sharing information between project templates in a multi-project template be creating an [IWizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.templatewizard.iwizard.aspx) implementation called [GlobalParams](http://globalparams.codeplex.com). It makes the information from the solution template level available to the child templates that also run the wizard by prefixing **ALL** solution level parameters with the word *global* and adding it to the child parameters.

If you used [GlobalParams](http://globalparams.codeplex.com) with the above template and the user entered "Test Project", the following would be true:

- **InterfaceTemplate.vstemplate** could access

  - `$safeprojectname$` = Test_Project.Interface
  - `$globalsafeprojectname$` = Test_Project
- **BusinessTemplate.vstemplate** could access

  - `$safeprojectname$` = Test_Project.Business
  - `$globalsafeprojectname$` = Test_Project

The above is an example of the safe project name but all parameters from the solution template are passed to child template See the [GlobalParams Documentation](https://globalparams.codeplex.com/documentation) for more information.