# Destination Directory parameter in Item Template - Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-templates

I have created a C# Item template and have included several template parameters. I would like to have the path of the newly created .cs file (using Add, New Item..) included in the file.

When creating C# Project templates, you can use this parameter in the template file:

```
$destinationdirectory$
```

Which will produce the path to the directory of the .csproj once created, something like:

```
C:\Users\username\source\repos\solutionfolder\projectfolder
```

When using the same parameter in an item template, the parameter isn't replaced (all other parameters are), the newly created .cs still contains:

```
$destinationdirectory$
```

What parameter can I use to get the path of the newly created .cs file? Failing that, the path to the solution the new item was created?

This [MSDN Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/ide/template-parameters?view=vs-2015) is the only reference of parameters for project/item templates I have found. It only includes about 15 parameters, which falls very short of how many there actually are.

If anyone has a more complete list i would be grateful, I have been plodding through the out of the box .cs item templates to find additional parameters:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47222951/8193524)

You can use:

```
$solutiondirectory$
```

for the directory of the solution, you can then combine other parameters to get the path of the item template. If MSDN could provide a list of all the reserved parameters this would have saved me a good few hours.