# Create a custom template in visual studio 2019 (multi-projects)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm creating a custom template with the next projects

[image]

In my root.vstemplate I have

[image]

The problem here is in the reference of each project, because each project take the name of `$projectname$`, how specify the correct reference in each project? When I create another solution with name SchoolApp, every reference can't take the name.

[image]

Comment: See the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24043435/5509738)

Comment: thank's fix the problem

Comment: @jmoyau Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider to answer it by yourself and change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)